# Редакция предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение:

Здесь мы сильны, применяя арматуру для низких окружающих температур из соответствующих слаболегированных сталей, для сложных условий в нефтегазодобыче со специальными конструкциями поворотной арматуры (сегментных клапанов и регулирующих шаровых кранов), а также чем всегда славился (...) — специальными решениями с использованием прямоходной односедельной арматуры для сложных технологических процессов.

Я сделала следующую редакцию:

Здесь мы сильны применением арматуры для низких окружающих температур из соответствующих слаболегированных сталей для сложных условий в нефтегазодобыче со специальными конструкциями поворотной арматуры (сегментными клапанами и регулирующими шаровыми кранами), а также — чем всегда славился (...) — специальными решениями с использованием прямоходной односедельной арматуры для сложных технологических процессов.

Допустима ли она?

Answer (score 1):

Конструкция "чем всегда славился Икс" - это разновидность вводного предложения, являющаяся попутным замечанием. Оно не нарушает структуру предложения и интонационно списывается в предложение. Кроме того, оно начинается с местоимения "чем". Все эти доводы говорят в пользу запятых: "...а также, чем всегда славился Икс, специальными решениями с использованием прямоходной односедельной арматуры для сложных технологических процессов".  Тире или лучше скобки нужны было бы при следующем построении предложения: "... а также - этим всегда славился Икс - специальными решениями с использованием прямоходной односедельной арматуры для сложных технологических процессов".

Comment: Спасибо. (Очень смеюсь)

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

Здесь мы сильны прежде всего применением  арматуры для низких окружающих температур из соответствующих слаболегированных сталей в  сложных условиях  нефтегазодобычи (со специальными конструкциями поворотной арматуры - сегментных клапанов и регулирующих шаровых кранов), а также -  чем всегда славился (...) — специальными решениями с использованием прямоходной односедельной арматуры для сложных технологических процессов.

Comment: Нет, мне кажется, здесь все-таки "чем всегда славился (...)" - это именно вставная конструкция, т.к. просматривается "применением арматуры, а также специальными решениями". "Чем" - это не приложение.

Comment: Я просто случайно пропустила тире.